# Remove Angular 2 component's selector tag with properties from HTML

Tags: angular, typescript, recursion, treeview

I have Angular 2 Component selector for my tree view:

```
   <navigation-bar [directories]="directories"></navigation-bar>
```

List looks like below :

```
<ul>
  <li class="nav-item  ">
            <a href="javascript:;" class="nav-link nav-toggle">
                <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
                <span class="title">Attendance</span>
                <span class="arrow"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li class="nav-item  ">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link ">
                        <span class="title">Attendance History</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item  ">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link ">
                        <span class="title">Attenance Reports</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item  ">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link ">
                        <span class="title">Attenance Settings</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
     <navigation-bar [directories]="directories"></navigation-bar> 
</ul>
```

Component code looks like below:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
        selector: 'navigation-bar',
        templateUrl: './app/home/navigationBarItems.component.html',

    })
    export class NavigationBarItemsComponent {
        @Input() directories: Array<Tree>;
    }
```

Component template looks like below:

```
<li class="nav-item " *ngFor="let dir of directories">
                <a href="javascript:;" class="nav-link nav-toggle">
                    <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
                    <span class="title">{{ dir.name }}</span>
                    <span class="arrow"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="sub-menu" *ngFor="let file of dir.child">
                    <li class="nav-item  ">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link ">
                            <span class="title">{{file.name}}</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <navigation-bar [directories]="dir.child"></navigation-bar>
                </ul>
  </li>
```

Since I have tree view with styles, the view isn't rendering properly because of selector element inside the list.

Any suggestions?

Edit: 
Made changes in following places as per the suggestion:

Componet.html:

```
<li class="nav-item" navigation-bar [directories]="directories"></li>
```

recursivecomponent.ts:

```
@Component({
    selector: '[navigation-bar]',
    templateUrl: './app/home/navigationBarItems.component.html',

})
```

recursivecomponent.html:

```
<li class="nav-item " *ngFor="let dir of directories">
                <a href="javascript:;" class="nav-link nav-toggle">
                    <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
                    <span class="title">{{ dir.name }}</span>
                    <span class="arrow"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="sub-menu" *ngFor="let file of dir.child">
                    <li class="nav-item  ">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link ">
                            <span class="title">{{file.name}}</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item" navigation-bar [directories]="dir.child"></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
```

**Output:**

```
<li class="nav-item" navigation-bar="" >    
            <li class="nav-item ">
                <a class="nav-link nav-toggle" href="javascript:;">
                    <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
                    <span class="title">parent1</span>
                    <span class="arrow"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
</li>
```

I observe one more "li" tag inside my list which is the reason for the collapse of my tree structure.

Comment: what element do you want to act as host of your component? you can define your component as an attribute selector

Comment: <li> should be my host and <navigation-bar [directories]="directories"></navigation-bar> was the selector

Comment: you're confused, `selector` is how angular finds host element in the DOM, your selector now is `selector: 'navigation-bar',`. If you make `li` the host,  what do you want to do with the contents of the `li`?

Comment: Sry my bad, yes it is

Comment: so what do you want to do with the `li` contents?

Comment: let me edit the post as per the change you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

If your host is already a `li` element, you cannot create a loop inside the component to render multiple instances of *that* component (that is, `li` element).

You'll have to re-think your approach, and use the `*ngFor` from the outside, which means that your NavigationBar component will handle only displaying a single `<li>` element.

From the outside, you'd use it as the following.

```
<navigation-bar *ngFor="let dir of directory" [directory]="dir"></navigation-bar>
```

And the template of NavigationBar component should be without the `ngFor` loop.

```
<li class="nav-item">
  <!-- ... -->
</li>
```

Comment: But I have to call this as recursive

Comment: Inside your recursion, you can still do `*ngFor` from the outside.